# Using jQuery to beautify someone else's html

Tags: jquery, html

I have a third-party app that creates HTML-based reports that I need to display.  I have *some* control over how they look, but in general it's pretty primitive.  I *can* inject some javascript, though.  I'd like to try to inject some jQuery goodness into it to tidy it up some.  One specific thing I would like to do is to take a table (an actual HTML <table>) that always contains one row and a variable number of columns and magically convert that into a tabbed view where the contents (always one <div> that I can supply an ID if necessary) of each original table cell represents a sheet in the tabbed view.  I haven't found any good (read: simple) examples of re-parenting items like this, so I'm not sure where to begin.  Can someone provide some hints on how I might try this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a html page like this:

```
<body><br/>
    <table id="my-table">`<br/>
        <tr><br/>
            <td><div>This is the contents of Column One</div></td><br/>
            <td><div>This is the contents of Column Two</div></td><br/>
            <td><div>This is the contents of Column Three</div></td><br/>
            <td><div>Contents of Column Four blah blah</div></td><br/>
            <td><div>Column Five is here</div></td><br/>
        </tr><br/>
    </table><br/>
</body><br/>
```

the following jQuery code converts the table cells into tabs (tested in FF 3 and IE 7)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabCounter = 1;
    $("#my-table").after("<div id='tab-container' class='flora'><ul id='tab-list'></ul></div>");
    $("#my-table div").appendTo("#tab-container").each(function() {                    
        var id = "fragment-" + tabCounter;
        $(this).attr("id", id);
        $("#tab-list").append("<li><span><a href='#" + id + "'>Tab " + tabCounter + "</a></span></li>");
        tabCounter++;
    });
    $("#tab-container > ul").tabs();
});
```

To get this to work I referenced the following jQuery files

- jquery-latest.js
- ui.core.js
- ui.tabs.js

And I referenced the flora.all.css stylesheet.  Basically I copied the header section from the [jQuery tab example](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Example)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with jQuery but it may make additional maintenance a nightmare. I would recommend against doing this / screen scraping because if the source ever changes so does your work around.

Comment: Well, I know that I can inject specific ID attributes into specific page elements that get rendered, and that the HTML source is otherwise unlikely to change in any meaningful way.  You have a good point, but with this particular 3rd-party app, I think this aspect of it is relatively safe.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds possible. With a combination of jQuery.append and jQuery.fadeIn and fadeOut you should be able to create a nice little tabbed control.

See the JQuery UI/Tabs for a simple way to create a set of tabs based on a `<ul>` element and a set of `<div>'s`: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest injecting an additional stylesheet and use that to show/hide and style ugly elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not interested in a HTML cleanup as HTML Tidy does, but in an interactive enhancement of static HTML components (e.g. turning a static table in a tabbed interface).

Some replies here already gave you hints, e.g. using Jquery Tabs, but i don't like the HTML rewrite approach in their answers.

IMHO its better to extract the content of the table cells you want with a JQuery selector, like:

```
var mycontent = $('table tr[:first-child]').find('td[:first-child]').html()
```

then you can feed this data to the JQuery UI plugin by programmatically creating the tabs:

```
$('body').append($('<div></div>').attr('id','mytabs'));
$('#mytabs').tabs({}); //specify tab preferences here
$('#mytabs').tabs('add',mycontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beautifying HTML is not such a simple process, because every line break between tags is a text node and arbitrary beautification creates and removes text nodes in manner that could be harmful to the document structure and likely harmful to the content.  I recommend using a program that has already thought all these conditions through, such as http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify